# How to use Jira.CreateOAuthRestClient from C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have downloaded Atlassian SDK from visual studio nuget manager. There is a method

public static Jira CreateOAuthRestClient(string url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string oAuthAccessToken, string oAuthTokenSecret, JiraOAuthSignatureMethod oAuthSignatureMethod = JiraOAuthSignatureMethod.RsaSha1, JiraRestClientSettings settings = null)

I have base Jira URL and a secret access token. However, the above method seems to have many parameters. Request someone to share a sample c# code how I can use this method to fetch JIRA issues in c# code.

consumerKey:?
consumerSecret:?
oAuthAccessToken:?
oAuthTokenSecret: ?

What should be the value of these parameters?